# Custom web-chat background image

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I am trying to make my own chatbot but am unsure of how to change the background image to my own jpg.

I have tried to place the code in the `<body>` and inside the `styleOptions` but none of my methods work.

Below is my html file:

```
<body style = "background-image: url('CorpBotOrchestrator/Images/whatsapp.jpg');">
    <div id="webchat" role="main">Loading...</div>
    <script>      
          styleOptions: {
            bubbleFromUserBackground: 'LightBlue',
            hideUploadButton: true,
            botAvatarImage: 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/v4sdk/media/logo_bot.svg?view=azure-bot-service-4.0',

            //make the speech bubbles round
            bubbleBorderRadius: 20,
            bubbleFromUserBorderRadius: 20,
          }

        }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
      })().catch(err => console.error(err));

    </script>
  </body>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry for the lack of a hi! I tried to edit it but there doesn't seem to be any changes...

Comment: StackOverflow removes common headings like “hi” https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325593/10708483

Answer (score 2):

You will want to instantiate your web chat in the following way to change the background image of the activities window. Be aware that, in the BotFramework-WebChat `styleSet` object, there is `activity` which represents the individual messages, cards, etc., that are sent, and there is `activities` which represents the window of scrolling messages. It is the latter we will be working with.

Also, be aware, that because you are directly specifying a DOM element and property, albeit via web chat, should some aspect of web chat receive an update that changes the element or property used, this can cause a breaking change for you. Additionally, you will need to pass all the property values necessary as, generally, this strips all default values from the webchat element you are working with.

```js
const styleSet = createStyleSet ( {
  bubbleBackground: 'blue',
  bubbleFromUserBackground: 'red',

  bubbleBorderRadius: 18,
  bubbleFromUserBorderRadius: 18,
} );

styleSet.activities = {
  ...styleSet.activities,
  backgroundImage: "url('<someUrlLink>')";
}

window.WebChat.renderWebChat( {
  directLine: [...],
  styleSet
});
```

Hope of help!

---

**EDIT**

`styleOptions` can actually be passed in using the spread operator into `styleSet`. In this way, you can continue to use the ease of `styleOptions` for customizing and largely remain within best practices of Web Chat.

```js
const styleOptions = {
  bubbleBackground: 'blue',
  bubbleFromUserBackground: 'red',

  bubbleBorderRadius: 18,
  bubbleFromUserBorderRadius: 18
}

const styleSet = createStyleSet ( {
  ...styleOptions,
} );

styleSet.activities = {
  ...styleSet.activities,
  backgroundImage: "url('<someUrlLink>')";
}

window.WebChat.renderWebChat( {
  directLine: [...],
  styleSet
});
```

Comment: Wrt your remark "Additionally, you will need to pass all the property values ..". Just to be sure; when I would like to change the styling of suggested actions, I would only have to pass the default property values of suggested actions as stated in defaultStyleOptions.js?

Comment: Any properties that are available to choose from in `defaultStyleOptions` would need to be specified via `styleSet`, if you wanted affect the look of Web Chat.

Comment: @Hessel, please see my updated solution regarding passing styleOptions into styleSet.

Comment: Thank you. This will help me with future customizations