# Microsoft Bot Framework angular webchat Background Image

Tags: angular, botframework, web-chat

I am Beginner in embedding angular webchat on one of the angular application. I have gone through the official documentation of "Microsoft Bot framework webchat" and able to include webchat in angular application. For branding purpose i am able to do changes for few of the default style options which is already available in webchat.js file but i am unbale to manipulate or write my custom code for inclusion of background image in chat widget in my angular component. It will be truly appreciable if you can provide me the way to just pick and use code for this scenario.
Here are the reference Link i have gone through : -
[Custom web-chat background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56982636/custom-web-chat-background-image)

Comment: What do you mean by "I am unable to write custom code in angular"?

Comment: what exactly to be written for webchat background so that stylesSet can accept it. i tried with the reference of reactjs code to include the style set but throwing error.